# Many-to-Many Inserts with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

Say I have two entities with about 20 properties per entity and a Many-to-Many relationship like so:

```
User (Id int,Name string, .......)
Issue (Id int,Name string, .......)
IssueAssignment (UserId,RoleId)
```

I want to create a new Issue and assign it to a number of existing Users. If I have code like so:

```
foreach(var userId in existingUserIds)
{
   int id = userId
   var user = _db.Users.First(r => r.Id == id);        
   issue.AssignedUsers.add(user);     
}

_db.Users.AddObject(user);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

I noticed it seems terrribly inefficient when I run it against my SQL Database. If I look at
the SQL Profiler it's doing the following:

1. SELECT TOP(1) * FROM User WHERE UserId = userId
2. SELECT * FROM IssueAssignment ON User.Id = userId
3. INSERT INTO User ....
4. INSERT INTO IssueAssignment

My questions are:
(a) why do (1) and (2) have to happen at all?
(b) Both (1) and (2) bring back all fields do I need to do a object projection to limit the
fields, seems like unnecessary work too.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some possible clues for you:

1. This is how EF behaves. `_db.Users` is actaully a query and calling `First` on the query means executing the query in database.
2. I guess you are using EFv4 with T4 template and lazy loading is turned on. T4 templates create 'clever' objects which are able to fixup their navigation properties so once you add a `User` to an `Issue` it internally triggers fixup and tries to add the `Issue` to the `User` as well. This in turns triggers lazy loading of all issues related to the user.

So the trick is using dummy objects instead of real user. You know the id and you only want to create realtion between new issue and existing user. Try this (works with EFv4+ and POCOs):

```
foreach(var userId in existingUserIds)
{
   var user = new User { Id = userId };
   var _db.Users.Attach(user); // User with this Id mustn't be already loaded       
   issue.AssignedUsers.Add(user);     
}

context.Issues.AddObject(issue);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, spot on with the answer. So Attach tricks the context into thinking the user is already loaded?

Comment: Yes exactly. That is the trick which works in many-to-many relation. `Attach` makes a user known to the context.